# How can create a plot showing an NFL team's yards and points per game over the past 10 seasons?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm looking to create several plots comparing statistics for NFL teams. In particular, I want to compare yards per game (YPG) and points per game (PPG) since 2008. Can this be automatically pulled from nfl.com using Mathematica? If so, how do I do so?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more to work from? What URLs are you trying to pull from? It's almost certainly possible to do what you want but the exact structure depends on what you need.

Comment: Sorry...here's the main URL: http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&role=TM&offensiveStatisticCategory=GAME_STATS&defensiveStatisticCategory=null&season=2018&seasonType=REG&tabSeq=2&qualified=false&Submit=Go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's as much as I feel like doing:

```
baseString = 
  Import["http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&\
conference=null&role=TM&offensiveStatisticCategory=GAME_STATS&\
defensiveStatisticCategory=null&season=2018&seasonType=REG&tabSeq=2&\
qualified=false&Submit=Go"];

stringLines =
  With[{dev = Length[#] - 21},
     Join[
      {#[[1]]}, 
      {StringRiffle@#[[2 ;; 2 + dev]]},
      #[[3 + dev ;;]]
      ]
     ] & /@ StringSplit[
    Select[
     StringSplit[baseString, "\n"],
     StringStartsQ[NumberString]
     ]
    ];

cleanData =
  Join[
     {ToExpression[#[[1]]], #[[2]]},
     Internal`StringToDouble /@ #[[3 ;; -4]],
     ToExpression@StringSplit[#[[{-4}]], ":", 2],
     ToExpression@#[[-3 ;; -2]],
     #[[{-1}]]
     ] & /@ stringLines;

Sort@cleanData[[All, {4, 6}]] // ListLinePlot
```

[Try it online!](https://wolfr.am/AKTNeiso)